# how to execute two Thread.sleep simultaneoulsy

Tags: java, android, multithreading

SO I'm trying to execute two thread sleep simultaneously.

Thread 1 should execute at every 20 sec and in mean time thread two should also execute at every 10 seconds.Problem is in Thread 2 I have to call AsyncTask and that AsyncTask is getting executed at every 20 sec instead of 10.

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    while (check) {
                        try {
                            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    if (nw.isConnectingToInternet() ==false) {

                                        //dosometask
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            Thread.sleep(20000);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();

           new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Log.d("TAG", "10 sec over");
                    while (check) {
                        try {
                            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    l1 = new Location_Provider(MainActivity.this);

                                    Locationcheck lchk = new Locationcheck();
                                    lchk.execute();
                                 }
                            });
                                Thread.sleep(10000);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
           }
```

Where am I wrong?please tell me..

Comment: Are you saying that timing is important for this program? So you want them to run such that ever 20 seconds both threads run at exactly the same time (And every 10 one of them runs)? Or is it okay if the executions don't line up?

Comment: First, your Log.d("TAG", "10 sec over"); ist at the wrong place, take it inside the while-loop, otherwise it is executed when the tread is started.

Comment: @NicholasRobinson yes you got that right.but my issue is AsyncTask.Thread 1 runs at every 20 sec and Thread 2 is also getting executed at every 10 second but the AsycTask which I'm using inside Thread 2 is not getting executed at every 10 second. Am I making sense..?

Comment: @user3667949 I think so.. You want the overlapping call to take place at the same time?

Comment: @NicholasRobinson Yes.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to guarantee that. You can try to use the system time to work out a laps of 10 seconds. But there isn't even a way to gaurentee that `Thread.sleep(1000)' sleeps for exactly a second, due to the way the operating system schedules threads, so to get to separate threads to line up for any period of time is statistically impossible unless you have access to your OSs scheduling function.

Comment: Ohkay..Well Thanks..